# How to use "OR" using Django's model filter system?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, logical-or

It seems that Django's object model filter method automatically uses the AND SQL keyword.

For example:

```
>>> Publisher.objects.filter(name__contains="press", country__contains="U.S.A")
```

will automatically translate into something like:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM publisher
WHERE name LIKE '%press%'
AND country LIKE '%U.S.A.%'
```

However, I was wondering whether there was a way to make **`OR`**? I can't seem to find it in the documentation (oddly enough, searching for 'or' isn't really useful).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can use [Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) to do what you want, by bitwise OR-ing them together:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Publisher.objects.filter(Q(name__contains="press") | Q(country__contains="U.S.A"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without [**Q()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q), you can also run **`OR` operater** as shown below:

```py
Publisher.objects.filter(name__contains="press") | \
Publisher.objects.filter(country__contains="U.S.A")
```