# Django Q object not working

Tags: django, python-2.7, mongoengine, django-q

I want to make a or query with Django filters. The code I have seems easy but it does not work. I have read a lot for answers but nothing worked for me. What is the fault?

```
from django.db.models import Q
from models import Processoren

cpu = [
    "Intel",
    "AMD"
]

queryset = Processoren.objects.filter(Q(naam__contains=cpu[0]) | Q(naam__contains=cpu[1]))

#queryset = Processoren.objects.filter(naam__contains=cpu[0])

print queryset
```

The commented line of code does working but the one above does not.

Here is the documentation of the Q object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

And here a related question but that does not work for me:
[How to use OR using Django's model filter system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166361/how-to-use-or-using-djangos-model-filter-system)

What is wrong or what do I forget?

Comment: What is the relation to mongoengine?  Is `Processoren` a mongoengine model?

Comment: @Ross That is a model from models.py

Comment: A Django model or a MongoEngine Model - theres a difference as MongoEngine won't support the Django Q but a django model should.

Answer (score 0):

This code work as expected.  It produces pretty correct SQL query:

```
SELECT "app_processoren"."id", "app_processoren"."naam"
FROM "app_processoren"
WHERE ("app_processoren"."naam" LIKE '%Intel%' OR
       "app_processoren"."naam" LIKE '%AMD%')
```

Something wrong with your data.  Are you sure that records with `naam='AMD'` are exist?  May be they are have different case ('Amd' for example)?  Try `__icontains` instead of plain `__contains`.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yes I am sure that works because this line works fine:
`queryset = Processoren.objects.filter(naam__contains=cpu[0])`

Also if I do: `cpu[1]`, I also tried icontains.
So we can exclude that the data is right?