# How can I do to add the condition AND using exlude?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have this query :

```
MyTable.objects.filter(date=date).exclude(starthour__range=(start, end), endhour__range=(start, end))
```

But I want exclude the queries that `starthour__range=(start, end) AND endhour__range=(start, end)` not OR. I think in this case the OR is used.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166361/how-to-use-or-using-djangos-model-filter-system) help?

Comment: no, your two conditions are converted to a logical ***AND*** operation @Bob

Comment: No, this is just a consequence of [*de Morgan's law*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_Law).

Answer (score 0):

This is consequence of [*De Morgan's law* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_Law), this specifies that *¬ (x ∧ y)* is *¬ x ∨ ¬ y*. This thus means that the negation of *x* and *y*, is *not x* or *not y*. Indeed, if we take a look at the truth table:

```
 x | y | x ∧ y | ¬x | ¬y | ¬(x ∧ y) | ¬x ∨ ¬y
---+---+-------+----+----+----------+---------
 0 | 0 |   0   | 1  | 1  |    1     |    1
 0 | 1 |   0   | 1  | 0  |    1     |    1
 1 | 0 |   0   | 0  | 1  |    1     |    1
 1 | 1 |   1   | 0  | 0  |    0     |    0
```

So *excluding* items where *both* the `starthour` is in the`(start, end)` range *and* `endhour` is in the `(start, end)` range, is *logically* equivalent to allowing items where the `starthour` is *not* in the range, *or* where the `endhour` is not in the range.

## Using and logic

You can thus make a disjunction in the [**`.exclude(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) call to filter out items that satisfy one of the two conditions, or thus retain objects that do not satisfy *any* of the two conditions:

```
MyTable.objects.filter(date=date).exclude(
    Q(starthour__range=(start, end)) | Q(endhour__range=(start, end))
)
```

## Overlap logic

Based on your query however, you are looking for *overlap*, not for such range checks. It will *not* be sufficient to validate the `starthour` and `endhour`. If you want to check if two things overlap. Indeed, imagine that an event starts at 08:00 and ends at 18:00, and you filter for a range with 09:00 and 17:00, then both the `starthour` and `endhour` are *not* in the range, but still the events overlap.

Two ranges *[s<sub>1</sub>, e<sub>1</sub>]* and *[s<sub>2</sub>, e<sub>2</sub>]* do *not* overlap if *s<sub>1</sub>≥ e<sub>2</sub>*, or *s<sub>2</sub>≥ e<sub>1</sub>*. The negation, the condition when the two overlap is thus: *s<sub>1</sub>< e<sub>2</sub>* and *s<sub>2</sub>< e<sub>1</sub>*. We thus can exclude the items that overlap with:

```
# records that do not overlap

MyTable.objects.filter(date=date).exclude(
    starthour__lt=end, endhour__lt=start
)
```